# What children is a figcaption tag allowed to have?

Tags: html, figure

I'm a new web developer trying to understand the proper use of a figcaption tag.

What sort of children is it allowed to have? I was hoping to divide a figcapition's content into multiple `<p>` children but am not sure if that's semantically correct.

Comment: Just about anything: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content but it's a matter of opinion as to what's practical, even semantically, albiet less so.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps clear it up

Comment: A semantic example could be phrasing tags like `<i>`, `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<cite>`, `<samp>`, etc.

Comment: Report gaps for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can contain any "flow content", which is quite a lot, i.e. almost everything you might think of in that context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption)